# Auto Redirect to Mobile Site

Tags: mobile, web

I want when a mobile device, (such as Android Phone; Tablet, iPad, iPhone, iPod, or any other mobile device) to redirect to the mobile site instead of the actual site, but I'm not sure how to do this.

In my case, the URL for my main site is super-short.freeoda.com and the mobile url is http://mobile.dudamobile.com/site/super-short_freeoda_2/

Comment: Try using user agent detection there are a lot of examples out there

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it quick and dirty, you might want to check out [PHP Mobile Detect](https://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/) for  simple mobile redirects. It does some basic categorization into mobile, tablet, and the main platforms (iOS, Android, BB, etc.) based on a well-crafted regex on User-Agent strings.

Taking it further, you can try device databases like [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) or [Device Atlas](https://deviceatlas.com/), but they're more heavy-weight.

To be conscientious, make sure to include a clear link back to the "full" or "desktop" site to account for possible mis-detections.